# How can we give transition when expanding contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

```js
$('.inf-read-btn').on('click', function() {
  // Find the container whose button was clicked
  var $container = $(this).closest('.inf-frame-text');
  // find the p inside it
  var $elem = $container.find('p');

  // toggle the p element for that container
  $elem.toggleClass('is-active');

  $('.inf-frame-text p').not($elem).removeClass('is-active');
});
```

```css
.inf-frame-text {
  margin-top: 120px;
  &:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  p {
    height: 62px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  p.is-active {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

.inf-read-btn {
  display: block;
  color: #00ffbf !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inf-frame-text three">
  <p> For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything
    that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. </p>

  <div class="inf-read-btn-grid three">
    <a class="inf-read-btn"> Read More + </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hey guys, here when we click readmore button the text will expand but it suddenly happening or its happening like a sudden jumb. So i need to give transition for that. Can you help me using my java script codes?

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS but add class to paragraph, because adding CSS to P tag is bad practice

```
.inf-frame-text {
    margin-top: 120px;
}
.inf-frame-text:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.inf-frame-text p {
    max-height: 62px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s all ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in;
    -moz-transition: 1s all ease-in;
    -ms-transition: 1s all ease-in;
}
.inf-frame-text p.is-active {
    max-height: 1000px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Why adding CSS to a `p` tag is bad pratice ?

Comment: @Arkellys because it will apply all p tag in inf-frame-text class, Now imaging if there are more than one p tag then it would be difficult later on.

Comment: Hi Arkellys, it's not working...that's why i'm confused. And also thanks for the advise:))

Comment: @Danish Change css of p and p.is-active and it will work for you

Comment: No Arkellys, what i'm saying is giving style doesn't work. I'm looking for any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

since you're using jQuery try this:

```
$elem.animate({
   height: "toggle"
});
```

give your p an inline style of display none first, so when you're clicking jquery will take care the expand/collapse animation

Comment: Hi Erwin Sanders, but the problem is we need to show few part of the paragraph so we can't hide paragraph completely..is there any other possibilities?

Comment: what about using clip style? can take a look at this [CSS Clip](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_clip)